# I use azure with several web roles and 1 cache server. Will cached object be automatically updated in cache server when I change property in object

Tags: c#, caching, azure

I have this code

```
    Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache cache;
...
    User user = (User)cache["cacheKey"];
    user.Name = "NewUserName";
```

Will cached User object be automatically updated? Or I need to call clearing cache and put new value into the cache.

Will it be applied on all web roles, or maybe I am doing something wrong. I need to be able to edit cached object and this changes should be applied for both azure web roles

Comment: I guess it depends on what type of cache storage that is being used by the cache manager. If it is a in-memory-cache then I think it would work without extra effort.

Comment: `cacheManager`? What's that then?

Comment: I have updated the question. I use DataCache

Comment: @Sergey In previous comment, that I've deleted because it was based on my guesses more than documentation or practical experience, I've asked why don't you try it?

Comment: @PLB, agreed, my answer is based only on the documentation, rather than a test which would be fairly simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationserver.caching.datacache.item%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790944%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) on MSDN, I believe `user` will be a deserialization of the cached object, effectively your local clone.

So no, you will not be updating the actual cached object. Once you have made you changes you will have to update the cached object. Using either,

```
cache.Put("cacheKey", user);
```

or

```
cache["cacheKey"] = user;
```